# R program keeps getting numeric(0) answer

Tags: r, probability

I am a beginner in R. Here's the formula I'm trying to code to find the lambda that maximizes the log likelihood of some bigrams. When the bigrams are not found, the P_b (bigram) function fails, but the P_u (unigram) function should provide the unigram result (lambda = 0).

It works for bigrams that are found. When they're not found, tho, I only get numeric(0), not the unigram result.

[image]

```
p.mix <- function(w2, w1) {

  (1-lambda) * uni.dfrm$prob[uni.dfrm$token==w2] + lambda * p.bi(w2,w1)

}
```

The p.bi() function looks complicated because of the indexing so I'm reluctant to post it but it does work when the bigrams are found. It just looks up the count of times w' appears after w and divides it by the times w appears, but I have to go through another vector of vocabulary words so it looks ugly.

When w' is never found occurring after w, instead of a zero count, there's no row at all, which is what apparently causes the numeric(0) result. That's what the mixed model is supposed to solve, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas how this can work?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a test for the case where `w2` is `numeric(0)` for example :

```
p.mix <- function(w2, w1) {
  if(length(w2)>0){
    res <- (1-lambda) * uni.dfrm$prob[uni.dfrm$token==w2] +
                lambda * p.bi(w2,w1)
  }else res <- 0

  res
}
```

**EDIT**

```
p.mix <- function(w2, w1) {
  if(length(w2) && length(uni.dfrm$prob[uni.dfrm$token==w2]) > 0)
    (1-lambda) * uni.dfrm$prob[uni.dfrm$token==w2] + lambda * p.bi(w2,w1)
  else 0
}
```

Comment: That isn't quite the way it's supposed to work ... the p.mix is supposed to give a number whether the bigram is found or not, so if the bigram is not found, the only result will be when lambda = 0, so the result should be the unigram probability for the 2nd word, not zero. 

But I understand what you're saying. I already tried that in the p.bi function ... hit enter too fast, oops ...

  if (identical(bigram.w2, numeric(0))) {
    result <- 0
  } else result <- bigram.w2$w.ij / w1

bigram.w2 returns one line: w, w', and w.ij, or count of w'|w. But, this all works only when the bigram is found.

Comment: It seems that anything added to numeric(0) equals numeric(0). And I can't seem to get the bigram to be plain old zero instead of numeric(0) when it's not found. I could restructure the mixed model but I think that will be hard to calculate the right lambda. Maybe R is not a good language for this, altho there should be a way to do it.